# Bad/Wrong use of typetraits C++

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits

I'm trying to use the typetraits `enable_if` but I have some troubles with the syntax probably...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename _T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<_T>::value> >
struct Point {
    _T x;
    _T y;
    Point();
};

template <typename _T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<_T>::value> >
inline Point<_T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<_T>::value> >::Point()
{
    this->x = (_T)0.0;
    this->y = (_T)0.0;
}
```

The error is:

```
1>c:\users\lukkio\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\templates\templates\templates\header.h(19): error C3860: template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list
```

I'm using visual studio 2015 on windows. Is it related to SFINAE somehow? How should my code be fixed to work?

Comment: `enable_if` makes little sense on a class template. SFINAE only happens with function templates, as part of overload resolution. You may be looking for `static_assert`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It can make sense for the purpose of enabling or disabling specializations, right?

Comment: Perhaps you want [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) if you're trying to guarantee the `Point` class is only instantiated with floating point types.

Comment: But I don't understand... what is the problem? I mean i know that static_assert is a solution for what I'm up to, but I'd like to know if there's a way to use the "enable_if" as well. Also... what about if I use an "enable_if" among the methods as well....

Comment: If you just want to get it to compile, make it `template <typename T, typename Whatever> Point<T, Whatever>::Point() { ... }` (your syntax for out-of-class definition of a template member is all wrong.) It still wouldn't make sense, but to each his own.

Comment: May I ask why it doesn't make sense?

Comment: `_T` is an invalid identifier. Don’t use underscore at the beginning of the word (that’s not the rule, but it makes a more complex rule simple).

Answer (score 2):

As you can read here under default template arguments http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Default_template_arguments, default template arguments should not be specified twice, so if you remove the part after typename = ..... at the constructor, I believe it should work

Comment: Should I write <code>template <typename T, typename = ></code> instead?

Comment: You should write `template <typename T, typename T2> Point<T, T2>::Point(). Might be that it is possible to solve it using an anonymous typename as you did before, but this works (using gcc)

Comment: It also should work if defined in the body of `struct`. **Edit**: Yes, it works. The following works, too: `template <typename _T, typename T2 = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<_T>::value> >
inline Point<_T, T2 >...`